# QGIS - WHERE SQL within a processing.runalg statement for v.surf.rst in python console

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sql, qgis-python-console

I'm creating lots of raster files with grass:v.surf.rst so rather than using the graphical interface I wanted to use the python console (and potentially put in in a script at some point).  However when I try and run a script copied from the history I get a syntax error if I include the WHERE SQL syntax.  If I remove "x" <> 3.54 and just leave empty double quotes it works fine.
An example of the code:

```
processing.runalg("grass:v.surf.rst","file://drive/filename.csv?type=csv&xField=x&yField=y&spatialIndex=no&subsetIndex=no&watchFile=no",""x" <> 3.54",None,"DD275",40,40,300,0.001,2.5,1,0,0,False,False,"1.5,5.25,20.5,32.5",0.1,-1,0.0001,"//drive/filename.tif",None,None,None,None,None)
```

Is there a different process for the where statement in the console?

Comment: I think there might be an issue with your double quotes. Try replacing `""x" <> 3.54"` with `'x <> 3.54'`

Comment: Hi @Joseph, Sadly it doesn't seem to help, I've tried that one as well as: `'"x" <> 3.54'` and `"x <> 3.54"` and `"'x' <> 3.54"` and `"x" <> 3.54` and `'x' <> 3.54` without luck.